# Binding multiple events and run a function when all events are fired! JS, Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I want to bind two mouse events to a function (mousedown and moucemove). But I want to run the function only if both events are fired.

This will bind each event to to the function: (It's not what i want)

```
$("#someid").bind("mousedown mousemove", function (event) {  someFunction();  });
```

I can do this and it works:

```
$("#someid").bind("mousedown", function (event) {  
     someFunction();
     $("#someid").bind("mousemove", function (event) {
         someFunction();
     });
});

$("#someid").bind("mouseup", function (event) {
    $("#someid").unbind("mousemove");
});
```

**Is there a better, quicker way to do this???**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind only to the *mousemove* event. If the left mouse button is pressed while you move, event.which will be 1.

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 1) {
        //do some stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, this is much better! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want the `mousemove` handler work only when the mouse button is pressed down? If so, I'd suggest using some kind of boolean **flag**. You toggle its state on `mousedown` and `mouseup` events:

```
var flag = false;
$('#someid')
    .on('mousedown', function(e) {
        flag = true;
    })
    .on('mouseup', function(e) {
        flag = false;
    })
    .on('mousemove', function(e) {
        if (!flag) {
            return false;
        }

        // else... do your stuff
    });
```